# Angle between two frames

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have two frames:

[image: image description]

I want to find the yaw angle between the center of the frames according to the x (red) axis of the tb3_1 frame.I have the tf transforms available, wondering how to get the angle.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388578/angle-between-two-frames/) by [Roshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/85346/roshan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2021-10-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Tan-1(difference in Y/difference in X)?

---

Originally posted by [SSar](https://answers.ros.org/users/50955/ssar/) with karma: 53 on 2021-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1